# Is the area of a triangle with a vertex at circle center and other two inscribed $\frac{r\sin \theta}{2}$ or $\frac{r^2\sin \theta}{2}$?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

Spivak, Ch 11, problem 19a

> Consider points $A$ and $B$ on a circle with center $O$, subtending an
> angle of $\alpha=\angle AOC$ (Figure 29). How must $B$ be chosen so
> that the sum of the areas of $\Delta AOB$ and $\Delta BOC$ is a
> maximum? Hint: Express things in terms of $\theta=\angle AOB$.

The solution manual says

> If the radius of the circle is $r$, then the area of $\angle AOB$ is
> $\frac{r\sin{\theta}}{2}$, and the combined areas of $\Delta AOB$ and
> $\Delta BOC$ is
> $f(\theta)=\frac{r}{2}[\sin{\theta}+\sin{\alpha-\theta}]$. The [sic]
> has a maximum when $f'(\theta)=0$, which means that
> $\cos{\theta}-\cos{\alpha-\theta}=0$, hence $\theta=\frac{\alpha}{2}$.

[image]

**Is the area of $\angle AOB$ really $\frac{r\sin \theta}{2}$?**

As far as I can tell it is $\frac{r^2\sin \theta}{2}$

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note [dimensional analysis](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) indicates that, since $\sin \theta$ has no physical dimensions, then $\frac{r\sin \theta}{2}$ has a dimension of length, so it can't represent an area.